# Why does everyone sound like a robot in ps4 party chat

Tags: ps4, voice-chat

I logged on today and joined my friend's PS4 party, and everyone sounded like a robot with my headset on and with it off. I don't know what to do. I've turned the system off, I've unplugged and plugged in my headset, and I used a different headset. Does someone know what to do?

Comment: My guess is that's due to a high level of compression, but it could also because you or someone else enabled a special "robot-like" audio filter.

Comment: Could also just be really horrible latency between all the players; the person going 'robot' has horrible bandwidth.

Comment: I don't know if Arqade can answer this question because it has to do with a system that is controlled by Sony. We have no idea what Sony does with its voice chat feature.